# How to set up an Apache httpd test instance?

Tags: apache, jenkins

For our continuous integration tests under Ubuntu (run by Jenkins), I'd like to test the Apache `httpd` configuration especially with regard to the rewrite rules.

My plan of attack was (and is):

- create a temporary directory,
- copy the configuration there and amend some directives,
- fire up an Apache `httpd` on a non-standard port,
- run the tests,
- shutdown the `httpd`,
- remove the temporary directory.

The repository of our Apache httpd configuration can be found [here](http://git.wikimedia.org/summary/?r=operations/apache-config.git), my first stab at the test script [here](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/c/108880/1/test-it.sh).

The process however is very cumbersome as many paths are hardcoded and even the man page for `apachectl` just recommends reading the source for the various environment variables.

What is the recommended approach to set up such an isolated Apache `httpd` instance?  Are there instructions or field reports that I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to rewrite configuration files, I suggest using a tool like [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com) to create and provision a VM that runs your actual apache configuration. Running in a VM provides isolation (you can expose and remap TCP ports as needed) and it also gives you a development environment for interactive testing and debugging.

Instead of creating a temporary directory and modifying configuration files, you would run `vagrant up` as the first build step. With the right configuration, Vagrant will install whatever packages are needed and provision your apache configuration. Once the VM is up, you can run your tests.

It's easy to get started with Vagrant by walking through the [Getting Started Guide](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/) to see if it's right for you.

Comment: I'm aware of that, and Travis CI does a very good job at using VMs for testing, but for this question I'm interested in a solution without VMs.